# Need help for configuring standby DB with Oracle APEX

Tags: apex, standby

Hi I need configure Standby Database with Active Data Guard.
Our company uses Oracle APEX.
How to install APEX to reduce switchover downtime?

Or is it possible to install ORACLE APEX on a separate DBMS and set up a connection to a database with data?

Answer (score 0):

APEX is a product embedded in the database.

When you have a standby database and install APEX on the primary database, it is implicitly installed and synced also on the standby database.

What you need to configure is the ORDS that serves your APEX application so that it use a highly available connection string.

So instead of:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<SERVERNAME>:<PORT>/<SERVICE>
```

you'll rather have:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=120)(RETRY_COUNT=50)(RETRY_DELAY=3)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<SERVER1>)(PORT=1521)))(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<SERVER2>)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = <SERVICE>)))
```

or an EZConnect Plus highly available string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@"server1:1521,server2:1521/service?failover=on&load_balance=off&retry_count=3&connect_timeout=5&transport_connect_timeout=3"
```